# ¿Cual es diferencia entre usar list o no en python?

Tags: python, lista

Cual es la diferencia en estas 2 implementaciones

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
a=list([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list()` es un [constructor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(inform%C3%A1tica)), una función que crea objectos nuevos con los argumentos que le proporcionas. Cuando tu creas una lista de esta manera `a = [1, 2, 3]` Python implícitamente usa el constructor para crear la lista (`a = [1, 2, 3]` es exactamente lo mismo que `a = list([1, 2, 3])`).

La diferencia importante entre las dos maneras de manejar listas es que cuando usas `list()` tienes como garantía que el resultado es un objecto nuevo, sin cualquier otra referencia apuntando hacia el. Considera este ejemplo:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[1] = 9
>>> a
[1, 9, 3]
>>> b
[1, 9, 3]
```

Sin usar `list()`, copiando el contenido de `a` a `b` simplemente copia la referencia que apunta a la lista en la memoria, no la lista en si. Así que cuando modificas el contenido de `b` también lo modificas en `a` y viceversa.

Por el otro lado:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> b[1] = 9
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 9, 3]
```

Usando `list()` tu creas una copia nueva de `a` y la guardas en `b`. Como `a` y `b` ya son dos listas diferentes, cuando modificas una la otra no cambia.

Comment: Siendo precisos, `list(a)` crea una nueva lista y la inicializa *iterando* `a`, no hace ninguna copia de `a`. Sería equivalente a `list(x for x in a)`.